# How do you reduce the space between a poem and the poemline-counter

Tags: verse

In the following part of a poetic text (Sophocles’ »Antigone«, ll. 1137–1142), the verses are quite short:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}\setcounter{poemline}{1137}\poemlines{5}
τὰν ἐκ πασᾶν τιμᾷς \\
ὑπερτάταν πόλεων \\
ματρὶ σὺν κεραυνίᾳ· \\
καὶ νῦν, ὡς βιαίας ἔχεται \\
πάνδαμος πόλις ἐπὶ νόσου, \\
μολεῖν καθαρσίῳ ποδὶ Παρνασίαν
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

How do you reduce the space between the poemline-counter and the text?

[image: Sophocles, Antigone 1137–42]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of the [`verse`](https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf)-package, it says: »By default the numbers are typeset at the distance `\vrightskip` into the right margin.«

Therefore it is possible to change this length, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\vrightskip}{-15em}

\begin{verse}\setcounter{poemline}{1137}\poemlines{5}
τὰν ἐκ πασᾶν τιμᾷς \\
ὑπερτάταν πόλεων \\
ματρὶ σὺν κεραυνίᾳ· \\
καὶ νῦν, ὡς βιαίας ἔχεται \\
πάνδαμος πόλις ἐπὶ νόσου, \\
μολεῖν καθαρσίῳ ποδὶ Παρνασίαν \\
ὑπὲρ κλιτύν, ἢ στονόεντα πορθμόν.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]